# JTable not connecting to MS-Access database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to load records from my database to a JTable in Eclipse IDE so that I can capture user input to perform basic CRUD operations on the database and I currently have multiple tables that have successfully connected and are loading the data fine. However, one of my tables refuses to load any records and when I try perform an insert query, I get the following error:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> user lacks privelege or object not found: DATARATE in statement
> [insert into tblRAM (RAMName, Price, Rating, Description, DataRate)
> value(?,?,?,?,?)]

Here is the code:

````
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                //Gets the input from the text and combo boxes:
                String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
                s1 = txtRAMName.getText();
                s2 = txtPrice.getText();
                s3 = txtRating.getText();
                s4 = txtDescription.getText();
                s5 = (String) dataRate.getSelectedItem();              

                //A confirmation dialogue pane is created with a yes or no option. Determines if the code runs any further:
                int dialogueResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to add this record?", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                
                if(dialogueResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Connects to the database:
                        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/Documents/School/IT/2020 PAT Database.accdb");  
                        //Insert SQL statement that inserts the respective values. 
                        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into "+className+" (RAMName, Price, Rating, Description, DataRate) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                        pst.setString(1, s1);
                        pst.setString(2, s2);
                        int rating = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                        //Ensures the Rating variable is between 1 and 10:
                        if(rating<=10 && rating>=1)
                            pst.setInt(3, rating);
                        pst.setString(4, s4);
                        pst.setString(5, s5);
                        pst.executeUpdate(); 
                        //Confirms that a Record is added:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added");
                        //Runs the tableUpdate method to show the new record added:
                        tableUpdate();
                        //Resets the text box fields
                        txtRAMName.setText("");
                        txtPrice.setText("");
                        txtRating.setText("");
                        txtDescription.setText("");
                        txtRAMName.requestFocus();
                    } 
                    //Exception handling for ClassNotFoundException and SQLException:
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class Not Found\n"+e);
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input\n"+e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setBounds(10, 545, 175, 42);
        panel.add(btnAdd);```
````

Comment: Seems like the table has no column DataRate.

Comment: I double checked my MS-Access database and I do have it. @jarlh